# Check if string-formatted date time is equal to noon

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have an array of objects where each object has a date time as one value:

```
[
  {dt: "2019-11-29 12:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-29 3:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-29 6:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-30 12:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-30 6:00:00"}
]
```

I want to return all only those dates with time `12:00:00`.

Comment: So are those `Date`s or strings? I guess strings? If you plug that into `new Date()` you can then call `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` on it and compare it to `12` and `0` respectively.

Comment: `.filter()` is your friend. Also, your input is not what you expect. Since it's a single object inside an array instead of multiple objects, only the last dt key will be used. Probably want to change it to separate objects.

Comment: If it is array of objects and dates are strings, 
`var value = [{dt: '2019-11-29 12:00:00'}, {dt: '2019-11-29 3:00:00'}, {dt: '2019-11-29 6:00:00'},{dt: '2019-11-30 12:00:00'},{dt: '2019-11-30 6:00:00'}]`
You can use filter method.
`value.filter((val) => val.dt.includes('12:00:00'))`

Comment: That array is not valid JS by any stretch, please fix your question.

Comment: @Shilly I fixed the array of objects syntax in the way I think it's intended to be. (Right now the edit still has to be reviewed before it will be published.)

Comment: Or `let noonDates = data.filter(obj => /12:00:00/.test(obj.dt))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [array filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate over all date objects. For each object, first convert the date string to an [internal date representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then check if the hour, minutes and seconds fit noon.

```
const array = [
  {dt: "2019-11-29 12:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-29 3:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-29 6:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-30 12:00:00"},
  {dt: "2019-11-30 6:00:00"}
];

const result = array.filter((stringDate) => {
  const rawDate = new Date(stringDate.dt);
  return rawDate.getHours() === 12 && rawDate.getMinutes() === 0 && rawDate.getSeconds() === 0;
});
console.info(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function.I'm just comparing hours if you want to compare minutes and seconds then add one more level of if else

```js
const arr = [{dt: '2019-11-29 12:00:00'},{dt: '2019-11-29 3:0$.00:00'},{dt: '2019-11-30 12:00:00'},{dt: '2019-11-30 6:00:00'}];
console.log('without filter ===',arr)

let filteredArr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  let dt = new Date(arr[i].dt);
  console.log(dt);
  let hour = dt.getHours()
  let min = dt.getMinutes();
  let sec = dt.getSeconds();
  if(hour <= 12){
    filteredArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log('filtered arr ==',filteredArr)
```